# Void function C recursion

Tags: c, function, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have an exercise to do in C in which I need some help.  I have to write a recursive function (`checkModOfPrevSum()`) that will check a list of stored numbers if the value of each `node%sum_of_previous_nodes == 0`.

For each node, it has to print the value of the node, the sum of the previous nodes and a "yes" or "no" depending on if `node_value%sum_of_previous_nodes == 0`. The printing must be done in reverse order.

The function I have to use is this:

```
void checkModOfPrevSum(struct list *node, int sum) {.........}
```

Not allowed to use any while or for loops.

Example, if the list is the one below : (node with value 5 is head)

```
5  2  3  6  1  7  4
```

the result must be :

```
4 [24] (YES) - 7 [17] (NO) - 1 [16] (YES) - 6 [10] (NO) - 3 [7] (NO) - 2 [5] (NO) - 5 [0] (YES)
```

How can I write the code?

Comment: Have you made an attempt? :-) If so, please add it to the question and try to make sure it is a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question)[https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Lambis Manoussakis  Why is there  4 [24] (YES)? That is why is 4 % 24 equal to 0?

Comment: Also "shouting" is frowned upon among SO community.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a zero-effort requirements dump.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) ---- [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) --- [ask]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: ["3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having solving it.**"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Please [edit] the question to improve it. Please, also read this [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Answer (score 1):

We beginners should help each other.

The assignment is not easy to do for such beginners as me and you.:)

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void insert( struct node **head, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        struct node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        tmp->data = a[i];
        tmp->next = *head;
        *head = tmp;
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }        
}    

void checkModOfPrevSum( struct node *head, long long int sum)
{
    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        if ( head->next != NULL )
        {            
            checkModOfPrevSum( head->next, sum + head->data );
            printf( " - " );
        }            

        printf( "%d [%lld] (%s)", head->data, sum, sum % head->data == 0 ? "YES" : "NO" );
    }        
}    


int main( void ) 
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    int a[] = { 5, 2, 3, 6, 1, 7, 4 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    insert( &head, a, N );

    checkModOfPrevSum( head, 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4 [24] (YES) - 7 [17] (NO) - 1 [16] (YES) - 6 [10] (NO) - 3 [7] (NO) - 2 [5] (NO) - 5 [0] (YES)
```

Of course the list implementation is not complete. You can develop it further as you like.

Comment: `if ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;` This should not be a `while` ? linus style is hard to read :p.

Comment: @Stargateur Why should it be a while? It is just one statement that check whether the passed node is NULL or is not NULL and adjusts the head accordingly.

Comment: What is the purpose so ? I don't understand what is your goal to add this `if` if it's not a `while`. You want to insert after one elem of this list ?

Comment: @Stargateur The function allows either to insert an array when the list is  empty or after some node of a non-empty list. If the list is empty then the head is changed in the first iteration of the for loop. If the list is not empty then the next node after the given node is changed in the first iteration of the for loop.

Comment: @Stargateur The function inserts an array after the given node (not necessary the head) in the list. You should consider the case when the list is empty.

Comment: @Stargateur You are right, When the list is empty the if statement is not executed. But is the given node after which the array should be inserted then the function has to start changing the node that is ( *head )->next.